# In a 2 income family, is it more tax beneficial for the lower income spouse be the Primary Caregiver (Ontario)?

Tags: taxes, canada, ontario, child-care

My wife and I just had a new daughter. My wife applied for the 4 in 1 newborn package and she was designated as the primary caregiver and applied for the child care benefits.

Since she makes more than me (I'm in a much lower tax bracket than her), does it make more sense for me to be the primary caregiver and apply for CESG grants and other government child care benefits?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no difference** because CESG grants are calculated using *family income*, the sum of both your salaries. This [link](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/resp-reee/cesp-pcee/csg-eng.html) explains it.

If your net family income is lower than 44,701$ the CESG grants are more generous; a 500$ for [CLB](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/resp-reee/cesp-pcee/clb-eng.html) is added plus 100$ per year. Some conditions apply naturally.

For maximum return, open CESG before your daughter turns 7 years old.
Also, upon opening the account, put yourself as cosubscriber, your wife as subscriber.